# warmup time for MPI+OpenMP code on HPC cluster

Tags: performance, optimization, distributed-computing, slurm, hpc

I have written a C++ code which uses MPI + OpenMP.

I run it on a HPC cluster.

I am timing particular functions / parts of the code, by the quick-and-dirty way, with `chrono`.

`time0 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`,

`time1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();`,

`std::cout << "It took" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(time1 - time0).count() << std::endl;`

I know this is not exact, and profiling tools shall be used, but I just want to get an indication of how much time each part of the code takes, etc.

I am printing the output of these timings to the stdout only from rank 0.

The code runs iteratively through a for-loop.

The first few iterations of the for-loop take an enormous (10 - 20 x time) amount of time compared to all the next ones.

The ones which take less time are to be expected, and I would expect ALL the loop iterations to take roughly the same amount of time as these ones.

Nothing changes in terms of computational effort between them, they compute the same thing, always.

**Is this something to be expected, a warmup time?**

For the MPI part, the code uses `MPI_Alltoall` only. This is a blocking operation. Apart from this, nothing else for MPI.

For the OpenMP part, the code uses `#pragma omp parallel for (collapse(2,3))`. Apart from this, nothing else.

The submission script contains the below (1 node has 4 NUMA regions and each NUMA region has 8 physical cores each with 2 logical threads):

```
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8

export OMP_PLACES=cores
export OMP_PROC_BIND=true
mpirun -srun --distribution=block --hint=nomultithread ./my_app
```